# Meteor Collections are not displaying

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm following the book *Getting Started With Meteor* and I'm really not getting far because simple errors keep blocking me.

At this point in time I've started writing the initial app in the book in which we make a new global connection.

```
Lists = new Meteor.Collection("lists");
```

We then add some data to that collection.

```
lists.insert({Category:"DVDs", items: {Name:"Item Name",Owner:"me",LentTo:"Internet"}})
```

I can verify that the data is entered by checking in the console

```
lists.find({}).count(); //returns 2 
lists.findOne({Category:"DVDs"}) //returns the DVD category
```

However when I try to display this content in the DOM nothing is displayed.

```
<div id="categories-container">
  {{> categories}}
</div>

<template name="categories">

   <div class="title"><h3>My Stuff</h3></div>

    <div id="categories">
       {{#each lists}}
          <div class="category">
            {{Category}}
         </div>
       {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

This displays only my Title. I get no errors in the browser console or the command line console. Not sure how to diagnose this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By going off the comments here and by reading a bit more, the reasoning why was because there was nothing telling meteor that the template was defined.

This was solved by the following code:

```
Template.categories.lists = function (){
   return Lists.find({}, {sort: {Category: 1}});
}
```

This tells it to find all of the records in the Lists collection and sort them by Category.

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty sure the reason is because you have

```
    Lists = new Meteor.Collection("lists");
```

But then you do:

```
    lists.insert({Category:"DVDs", items: {Name:"Item Name",Owner:"me",LentTo:"Internet"}})
    lists.find({}).count(); //returns 2 
    lists.findOne({Category:"DVDs"}) //returns the DVD category
```

But you should do

```
    Lists.insert({Category:"DVDs", items: {Name:"Item Name",Owner:"me",LentTo:"Internet"}})
    Lists.find({}).count(); //returns 2 
    Lists.findOne({Category:"DVDs"}) //returns the DVD category
```

Because it is case sensitive. Then in your Template helper do a Lists.find({}) and you should be good to go.

Comment: I've been thinking that, and I've tried both cases with the same results. Would you say that best practice would be to use the same case for our variable as we do our collection name?

Comment: I believe you have to use the same case. If you look at all of the meteor examples that is what they do. First letter is always capitalized.

Answer (score 2):

Did you define a template helper to display your content?

You may need:

```
Template.categories.lists = function() {
  return Lists.find({});
};
```

Check out the documentation for specifics:

http://docs.meteor.com/#templates

For faceting on categories, you'll probably want to set a reactive session value.

Comment: Thanks Bjorn. I just added that and still, nothing. Nothing in either console.

However, this may be why I'm having such a problem. I do not know what reactive session value is because I'm not that far along in the book, but I'm not that far along in the book because this doesn't work.

Feeling pretty stuck.

Comment: Maybe you just want to start with the meteor tutorial. I didn't read a book to learn Meteor. http://www.meteor.com/examples/leaderboard

Answer (score 0):

To make your time with the book Discover Meteor easier:  If you have software that will compare two directories, get the book from git in a parallel directory to what you are typing in.  Then, when you have problems, go to that directory in the terminal and git checkout the chapter.  Now, compare the two folders and you'll see your spelling errors.

Learning quickly evolving stuff on the internet is a hard process.  A lot of the tutorials you find only work for a period of time.

But the meteor book is different.  They keep the code up.  I personally typed along, and found my errors were solved on a better read (**and often less thinking I knew what I was doing**).  I've talked two twenty-somethings through it, and they also consistently made new and creative punctuation or spelling choices for quite a while.  There are also

```
meteor add xxx
meteor remove xxx
```

commands that are easy to miss.

But please trust that source (assuming you just got it, and aren't working from some old pdf)  and doubt yourself, just for this tutorial.  :)

Comment: Yes I do believe I'm working from an old pdf, as in the book he defines the List variable as "var Lists" but the examples meteor gives do not use the var protocol.

Comment: You can download it again or view on web, using the same credentials as initially used.  I agree with the others that you will eventually need to reason your way out of this.  But it's ok to learn by following the book until further along.

Comment: I think you two are referring to different books. The OP is referring to Getting Started With Meteor and this answer is referring to Discover Meteor.

Comment: OOPS.  Yeah, I don't know anything about your book.  I imagine what I said about it being kept current in this period is correct, though.  Thanks, @landland!